# How to include empty strings in excel calculations

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Cell 1: ="" (Empty String)
Cell 2: =2  (Number)

When I try to add cell 1 and cell 2, excel gives me #VALUE error despite that I already format cell 1 as number. What can I do to let excel treat Cell 1 as Blanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUM:

```
=SUM(A1,A2)
```

it will ignore the empty string.

[image]